# can the shell be told to save command output?

Tags: shell, zsh

I'm thinking a hypothetical `CMDOUTPUT` would be useful:

```
locate -r 'regexp...'    # locate finds a file: /myfile.
                         # Shell puts `/myfile' string into CMDOUTPUT
vim $CMDOUTPUT           # No need to run locate again as with: vim `!!`
```

The `locate` command above is just an example. I want the output saved for *all* commands that I run so that if I need it I can access it quickly. (The output should still be printed by the command to stdout.) I don't want to do

```
CMDOUTPUT="$(...)"
```

or

```
command | tee /tmp/cmdoutput
```

or anything else that *I* have to do because that's more typing for me at the prompt for everything that I run: I want the shell to do it all in the background. Again, to make it clear: I am casually typing commands away and decide "Oh, I want to use the output of that last command in this command, let me just *retrieve* it...". Can I tell the **shell to store the output** somehow so that I can *retrieve* it.

If there's no option for it, is there some way that I can implement it that is as close to invisible as it can be, meaning exit codes from the command are not lost (...and that's all I can think of, but I'm sure there are other subtleties) etc. I'm primarily thinking of zsh, but answers for any shell would be useful.

Comment: did you try `locate -r 'regexp...' > result.txt`

Comment: @VBB: Just to make it clear, the locate command is just an example. I want the output saved for _every_ command I run. I don't want to do this redirection myself because: 1) more typing for me, 2) I have to worry about clobbering files etc. which is again more work for me. I'll update the question.

Comment: So you want to see _and_ save or just save?

Comment: @VBB: see and save. Should have mentioned that.

Comment: Maybe http://superuser.com/questions/479377/zsh-recording-of-input-output ?

Comment: @TomRegner: that's basically WoLpH's answer below fleshed out a bit. I was thinking myself that I'd have to create a wrapper shell that calls zsh itself and logs zsh's output. I could do it that way or mess about with the zsh command line editor, zle. I'm debating which way would be better. If I get something going I'll put it up, but in the meantime I'm hoping there's someone who knows of a simple but obscure setopt :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for. But it should provide a start :)

```
zsh | tee log >&1
```

Comment: Not a bad idea, but might be more trouble than it's worth. Firstly, the prompt will be captured too, and so I'd have to have the shell run some function before the commands themselves to trim/remove the log file, and secondly, of course, I'd have to exit twice to close the terminal (which would irritate me). I could probably implement the former, but _tricks_ to negate the second problem might be more dangerous.